# how to extract specific value using grep and awk

Tags: awk, grep

Im using `cat /etc/inetd.conf | grep '#'chargen`
and I receive

```
#chargen        stream  tcp     nowait  root    internal
#chargen        dgram   udp     wait    root    internal
```

how I can extract only once word #chargen from this output:

```
#chargen
```

Comment: Looking at the close(3/3) reasons you guys really agree what's wrong with the question. :D

Comment: @JamesBrown I am one of the three. And I went for no mcve. It's a tricky thing to choose the reason for some questions, and different people have different opinions for *good/bad question*. Actually there were many discussions about close reasons in socvr in the past. I usually would like to go for *no mcve* since that at least have more chance to lead OPs to show own efforts and provide mcve next time. Some answerers here so quickly and so easily to answer no-effort-showing questions, by this way encouraging OPs went on like that, and showing their own willingness to be abused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^#chargen/{print $1; exit}' Input_file
```

or

```
grep -m1 -o '#chargen' /etc/inetd.conf
```

Comment: how to make to output only one word #chargen not two

Comment: Updated, please try now.