# how to extract word from ps -aux

Tags: bash, awk, grep, aix

when i execute command  ps -ef | grep yypasswd
I receive this output.

```
testacc 25124194 2512312620   0 08:00:53  pts/0  0:00 grep yypasswd
```

how can extract with command from this output word "yypasswd"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55411436/how-to-extract-specific-value-using-grep-and-awk

Comment: this trick with awk doesnt work

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to extract the word you're grepping for?

Comment: In awk `$1` is the first field, `$NF` is the last.

Comment: I grep "yypasswd" from running proccess and I want to have output only word "yypasswd"

Comment: ok james thanks it help with $NF

Comment: Wait. You `grep` for a `string` from `ps` output and the only process that has the `string` is your `grep string` and you want to extrace the `string` from that?

Comment: Try this: `echo yypasswd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not clear what you're trying to do:

If you expect the following output:

```
yypasswd
```

then do

```
ps -ef | grep yypasswd | awk '{print $8}'
```

if you want the following output:

```
testacc 25124194 2512312620   0 08:00:53  pts/0  0:00
```

then do

```
ps -ef | grep yypasswd |  awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 ,$7}'
```

hope that helps.

Comment: consider grepping for `[y]ypasswd`, if that's the *actual* process you want, otherwise you risk the false-positive match (seen in the question) for `grep yypasswd`

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ef | grep -o yypasswd
```

From man grep :

> -o, --only-matching
>                 Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Just note that the ps line you post is the actual process of `grep` that you ran. To exclude this you could do :

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -o yypasswd
```

Another way to search for a process name is with pgrep :

```
pgrep -f yypasswd
```

pgrep wil give you the PID of the matched process

Comment: grep: Not a recognized flag: o

Comment: Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L]  [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
Usage: grep [-r] [-R] [-H] [-L] [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-insvxbhwyu] [-p[parasep]] pattern_list [file...]

Comment: ok but it still not recongnize paramter -o 

grep: Not a recognized flag: o

Comment: @Martin which OS are you using ? Also try the pgrep option in my updated answer

Comment: The aix tag is lit.

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
ps -ef | grep yypasswd | awk '{print $8}'
```

or using pgrep

```
pgrep -l yypasswd | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution

```
ps -ef | grep yypasswd | awk '/yypasswd/{print $NF;}'
```

Comment: You could lose the `grep`: `ps -ef  | awk '/yypasswd/{print $NF}'`

Comment: nope I cant. When execute without grep i have nothing. I m using Aix OS. So it is ksh

Comment: Oh yeah right. Cause non of the processes had the `yypasswd` except your `grep`. I'm not even going to ask why not just `echo yypasswd`

Comment: do you mean that this process does not active? as I entered ps -ef | grep yypasswd I think that it will search for me from active processes

Comment: If you grep for a process with `yypasswd` in it and you only get your `grep` process, it sounds like there are no other processes running with `yypasswd` in it's name? Not my downvote, by the way.

Comment: This is ridiculous. You use grep to search for yypasswd then pipe the result to awk to search for yypasswd again when  you already know it's present then you use awk to print the last word on the line which you know is yypasswd. You're also using `ps` to find the process that the subsequent pipe to grep is creating so that yypasswd will be present for the grep and then the awk to find. You could reduce this whole script to `echo 'yypasswd'`. Whatever it is you're really trying to do, this is not the way to do it.